# Custom listview/list with images in android with search bar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I'm very new to Android development.
I`m working with custom listview/list with images in android
with search bar 
 The problem is  **I can't go to the next class
when each item is clicked** 
here is my same screen shot

```
private void select(String item) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {
        Intent i = null;

        if (item.equals("Aerosol")) {
            intent = new Intent(Search.this,  Aerosol.class);
        }
        if (item.equals("Aluminium")) {
            intent = new Intent(Search.this,  Aluminium.class);
        }

        startActivity(i);

----------
```

Answer (score 2):

```
private void select(String item) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      try {
      Intent intent = null;

      if (item.equals("Aerosol")) {
            intent = new Intent(Search.this,  Aerosol.class);
      }
      if (item.equals("Aluminium")) {
            intent = new Intent(Search.this,  Aluminium.class);
        }

      startActivity(intent);
```

just change `i`  to `intent`

Answer (score 0):

You have added a OnItemClickListener in the adapter. Instead add a listener for the listview in the activity. Also move the select method to the activity.

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

 String item =text[position];
 select(item);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a listener to the listview.

```
  edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText01);
    listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView01);
    listview.setAdapter(new MyCustomAdapter(text, image));
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(  onListViewClicked );
```

Then add this method:

```
    OnItemClickListener onListViewClicked = new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

 String item =text[position];
 select(item);

        }
    };
```

Comment: LoL that the same as user936414